# How can I get Django to exit if it can't connect to the database?

Tags: django

If the database isn't up django throws a `django.db.utils.OperationalError`, but the process is still alive. This means supervisor will never attempt to restart it.

How can I make Django exit?

Comment: Do the normal Python exit mechanisms have no effect?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What I'm saying is that it doesn't actually exit in the first place. It just throws an error to stdout and stays there idle, it won't even try to connect to the database after the fact.